# how to call xml request in ruby using httparty?

Tags: ruby, xml

while calling xml request api in ruby it is getting xml parser error as response.

**API call**

```
require 'httparty'

    response = HTTParty.post("http://www.99acres.com/99api/v1/getmy99Response/test/uid/",
    :headers => {"Accept" => "application/xml", "Content-Type" =>"application/xml"},
    :body => '<?xml version="1.0"?><query>
    <user_name>test</user_name><pswd>testest</pswd><start_date>2019-03-25 12:03:00</start_date><end_date>2019-04-24 12:04:00</end_date></query>'

)
```

**Error Response**

> `ERROR-0000`XML Parsing
>   Error

How to call XML request API calling in ruby?.

Comment: The code example you have provided does not work. The response is `{"response"=>{"code"=>"1", "msg"=>"INVALID KEY"}}`. Your error response is also incomplete. Is that a truncated error message that you get from HTTParty? Does it come with a stack trace? Or is it a plaintext response from the remote API? What is the **exact** and **complete** response in your terminal when you make the request? Since you have not included a working code sample and you have not included a complete error response, it's unlikely that you will get any useful response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote correct request to API, but looks like they just don't give you access to API, looks like your login credential not correct, but there no problem with your code!

This response from API!

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7ff11da769b0 parsed_response={"response"=>{"code"=>"1", "msg"=>"INVALID KEY"}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["nginx"], "content-type"=>["text/xml;charset=UTF-8"], "content-length"=>["85"], "content-security-policy-report-only"=>["block-all-mixed-content; report-uri https://track.99acres.com/csp_logging.php;"], "etag"=>["\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\""], "date"=>["Wed, 24 Apr 2019 18:46:46 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"], "set-cookie"=>["99_ab=20; expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 18:46:46 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/"]}>
```